# Echo duration of video in seconds without decimals

Tags: ffmpeg

If I use ffprobe to output the duration of a video file with:

```
ffprobe -i input.mkv -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

I will get something like

```
3658.342000
```

How can I get the output in second only without the decimals? I do not mind if ffmpeg or Mediainfo has a better function for this. I just need to get the output in seconds.

*I am using CMD in Win10.*

Comment: I am unaware of an option within `ffprobe` to do what you want, but you can truncate or round the duration value using your preferred shell or scripting language.

Comment: With cmd you have to write your own rounding function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116014/batch-rounding-a-number Have you considered using Powershell? Then it's just `[math]::round(x)`. Note that you'll have to extract the number from ffprobe's output somehow.

Comment: `[math]::round((ffprobe 'input.mkv' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"))` works in powershell. Note the double brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a batch file to export the timings to a text file and then turncate the value as a set variable.

```
ffprobe -i {filepath$} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >> duration.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,8 delims=\ " %%a in (duration.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%i in ("%%a") do set _stime=%%i
)
```

Comment: You've gotta try powershell some time. You won't regret it.